# Why Im falling trough the plane?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

When Im pressing LMB, Im falling trough the plane

Video about the problem: https://youtu.be/aLUFHlolT8E

This is for Unity 4.5.5, and I have "First Person Controller" with code down there

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class run : MonoBehaviour {

public float speed = 6.0F;
public float jumpSpeed = 8.0F;
public float gravity = 20.0F;
private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
public float radius;
public float force;

void Blow () {
    Collider[] col = Physics.OverlapSphere (transform.position, radius);
    foreach (Collider c in col) {
        if (c.name != "Plane"){
            c.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddExplosionForce (force, transform.position, radius);
        }
    }
}

void Update() {
    CharacterController controller = GetComponent<CharacterController> ();

    if (controller.isGrounded) {
        moveDirection = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis ("Vertical"));
        moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection (moveDirection);
        moveDirection *= speed;

        if (Input.GetButton ("Jump"))
            moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
    }

    moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move (moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Blow ();
    }
}
}
```

I expected that my character would fly up to the air, but he goes down
And while this happens, cube acts normally

Comment: I recommend you take a step back and learn how to debug your code at run time. Here are a few of the many resources available: [Navigate through code with the Visual Studio debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/navigating-through-code-with-the-debugger), [Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), and [Debugging C# Code in Visual Studio | Mosh](https://youtu.be/u-HdLtqEOog).

Comment: Why are you still on 4.5.5?

Answer (score 1):

I Have Watched The Video And First Of All:

The Value 1000 As A Explosion Force Is too strong and it will basically cause the player to clip through the plane then fall

Second Of All:

The Grenade Is Located Above The Player, so You Should Lower Even More If You Want Him To Fly Up.

If You Want To Fix The clipping Issue Go To

Edit>ProjectSettings>Time>FixedTimeStep

Change FixedTime Step To A Smaller Value Like 0.02
But do Know The smaller This Value Is, the Harder It Is For The Program to Run

Comment: To Grenade Is higher Than The Player Jump height so he is going down instead of up

Comment: put The Force To A Value of 10